# Where to put One-Off Computer-Wide Software Folders?

Tags: folder, directory, symbolic-link

I am pretty new to Linux so pardon the ignorance.

I am installing an application (a wiki server) on my system but am not doing so through aptitude as I can only grab a tar.gz of the package.  This application will really be used by all users so it doesn't feel appropriate to install it in my home directory.  Where should I put the folder of files?  I would think that /usr/bin is the place, but I usually just see binary and linked files in there, which leads me to believe I should have the folder elsewhere and then drop a link to the executable in the /usr/bin folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One good place to put this is under `/srv`, typically something like `/srv/wiki.example.com`.  The [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM) endorses this location.

Another option is something like `/home/wiki` or `/home/httpd`.

Putting it in `/usr/bin` is not a good idea; that should be reserved for programs installed by Ubuntu.

`/usr/local/bin` is a better place to put a symlink to the program.

Answer (score 2):

I did not know about `/srv`, so +1 to poolie, but I would personally simply use `/usr/local/`, `/usr/share/`, or `/usr/local/share`. Not sure which goes where, but they all seem good candidates to me.

Comment: `/usr/local` would be a reasonable place for it.  `/usr/local/share` is not so good because that's [for architecture-independent data files](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREARCHITECTUREINDEPENDENTDATA) not programs.  `/usr/share` has the same problem and also is meant to be only changed by the distribution.